# Where can we translate the StackExchange interface?

Tags: feature-request

Although this is not really specific to the Esperanto instance, this is the one that made me ask the question. So is there already a place to translate the StackExchange interface?

Obviously here the goal would be to translate it to Esperanto, but other language related instances might benefit from such a localization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Exchange uses [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/) to translate the user interface, but that isn't enabled on a standard Stack Exchange site. A new site must be first be created (for example, https://eo.esperanto.stackexchange.com/), and then the translation is enabled for that site.
Before doing that, Stack Exchange would first look for a person who understand well the language that is going to be used on the site, who will be appointed CM with the task to follow those sites using that language.

At the moment, Stack Exchange doesn't plan to add more translated sites, though. See [How can I propose a non-English site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/how-can-i-propose-a-non-english-site)

For more details about localized sites and the use of Transifex for Stack Exchange site, see the questions tagged [transifex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transifex) or [localization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization+-transifex) on *Meta Stack Exchange*. The list of [bugs not yet resolved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+localization+-transifex+-status-completed) gives an idea of which issues a site localized in Esperanto would have too.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Please let me know if any plane to propose an Esperanto translation come into consideration.

Comment: When they accept again the proposal of non-English sites, I will be glad to propose the Esperanto version of _Esperanto Language_.

Comment: Given that Esperanto is by its nature an universal language, it could be they consider it more useful than creating a site in Italian, for example. I cannot say Esperanto is as universal as English, but certainly it's thought not to be linked to a nation or the nationality of people speaking it.

Answer (score 2):

The 3 non-English Stack **Overflow** sites (those for asking **programming** question phrased **in** these natural languages) have a translated UI:

- [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

In contrast, currently none of the Stack **Exchange** sites **about** (specific) non-English natural languages seem to have a UI in the respective language:

- [German Language Stack Exchange](https://german.stackexchange.com/)
- [French Language Stack Exchange](https://french.stackexchange.com/)
- [Spanish Language Stack Exchange](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/)
- [Russian Language Stack Exchange](https://russian.stackexchange.com/)
- [Italian Language Stack Exchange](https://italian.stackexchange.com/)
- [Portuguese Language Stack Exchange](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/)
- [Latin Language Stack Exchange](https://latin.stackexchange.com/)
- [Korean Language Stack Exchange](https://korean.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ukrainian Language Stack Exchange](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/)

Maybe it's because they're (other than the non-English Stack Overflow sites) all still "Beta", or maybe the Stack Exchange network doesn't feature non-English UIs except for the non-English Stack Overflow sites.

Comment: Thank you for this overview. Altough, to answer the question it would be better to have either a clear "StackExchange has a policy to not translate interfaces" or "The internationalization policy should be discussed at [some specific place]". Cheers

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I don't know either. Still, I thought the facts I stated in my answer might be useful and they were too long for a comment. AFAIK, on meta sites, the "Question posts are only for questions and answer posts are only for answers" is less strict than on the main Q&A sites, so that the meta sites can sometimes be used more forum-/discussion-like than a pure Q&A.

Comment: Note that most of these language Stack Exchange sites also target non-fluent learners of the language, and so may admit questions in English. In this situation, it is natural to be hesitant about translating the UI to the target language. At [PT.SE](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/43/84) (link content in Portuguese unfortunately), the general consensus is that English is regarded as the best "de facto" language for exchange in an international context. Ideally, the site's UI would support multiple languages, but there you have it, these "Beta" sites are not quite there yet.