# Ĉu ekzistas ebleco ŝanĝi interfaclingvon de la retejo «Esperanto Language Stack Exchange»?

Tags: discussion

Mi ne estas angloparolanto, do mi volus ŝanĝi lingvon de interfaco de la retejo [Esperanto Language Stack Exchange](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/) al io alia. Prefereble al esperanto. Tamen taŭgus la rusa/ukraina/belorusa aŭ eĉ la serba.

Sed mi ne trovis punkton "lingvo" en agordo. Ĉu la retejo ekzistas nur kun sola lingva interfaco?

Answer (score 0):

Malespereble «Esperanto Language Stack Exchange» havas nur anglalingvan interfacon. Laŭ mia scio ĝi *oficiale* eĉ estas tute anglalingva retejo *pri* Esperanto (ne *en* Esperanto), sed ĝia komunumo (la uzantoj) kaj la provizanto (la firmao Stack Overflow) permesas en ĝi enhavon (demandojn, respondojn, komentojn ktp.) kaj en la angla kaj en Esperanto: [Language of esperanto.stackexchange.com](https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3/1576)

Do:

> Ĉu ekzistas ebleco ŝanĝi interfaclingvon de la retejo «Esperanto Language Stack Exchange»?

Ne. (Malespereble.)

> [M]i volus ŝanĝi lingvon de interfaco de la retejo Esperanto Language Stack Exchange al io alia.

Tio ne eblas.

> Sed mi ne trovis punkton "lingvo" en agordo.

Vi ne povas trovi ĝin, ĉar ne estas agordo pri tio.

> Ĉu la retejo ekzistas nur kun sola lingva interfaco?

Jes, ĝi ekzistas nur en la angla.

Vidu ankaŭ la demandon [Where can we translate the StackExchange interface?](https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/203/1576) kaj ĝiajn respondojn.